# Stanford CoreNLP dedicated server ignoring annotators input

Tags: ruby, stanford-nlp

I'm running the CoreNLP dedicated server on AWS and trying to make a request from ruby. The server seems to be receiving the request correctly but the issue is the server seems to ignore the input annotators list and always default to all annotators. My Ruby code to make the request looks like so:

```
uri = URI.parse(URI.encode('http://ec2-************.compute.amazonaws.com//?properties={"tokenize.whitespace": "true", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos", "outputFormat": "json"}'))

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/v1.1/auth")
request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.body = text
response = http.request(request)
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

In the nohup.out logs on the server I see the following:

[/38.122.182.107:53507] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,lemma,ner,mention,coref,natlog,openie

....
  INPUT TEXT BLOCK  HERE
  ....

[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [2.0 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... 
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 2.259 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [5.1 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.6 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.2 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [7.2 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Feb 22, 2016 11:37:20 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 83 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Feb 22, 2016 11:37:20 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 267 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Feb 22, 2016 11:37:20 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 25 rules
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator mention
Using mention detector type: dependency
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator coref

etc etc.

When I run test queries using wget on the command line it seems to work fine.

```
wget --post-data 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' 'ec2-*******.compute.amazonaws.com/?properties={"tokenize.whitespace": "true", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos", "outputFormat": "json"}' -O -
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be appreicated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the request was being constructed incorrectly. The path should be in the argument to the Post.new. Corrected code below in case it helps anyone:

```
host = "http://ec2-***********.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"

path = '/?properties={"tokenize.whitespace": "true", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos", "outputFormat": "json"}'

encoded_path = URI.encode(path)

uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(host))
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.set_debug_output($stdout)
# request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/v1.1/auth")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(encoded_path)
request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.body = text
response = http.request(request)
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```